# How to access golang Struct Array inside another Struct?

Tags: go

How can I access the fields of a Struct Array which is inside another Struct?

My Structs as follows:-

```
type Company struct {
Id              bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
Company_name    string
Admin           UserMinimal
Process         []ProcessItem
}

type ProcessItemMinimal  struct {
Id              bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
Process_name    string
Processtype     int64   
}

type ProcessItem  struct{
ProcessItemMinimal  `bson:",inline"`
Sortorder           int64   
}
```

I need to store some data in []ProcessItem inside Company struct.
The data will be like this.

```
ProcessItem[0]=Process_name:"Enquiry",Processtype:0,Sortorder:0}
ProcessItem[1]=Process_name:"Converted",Processtype:1,Sortorder:1}
ProcessItem[2]={Process_name:"Enquiry",Processtype:1,Sortorder:2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for setting the data using [composite struct literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), it can be done like this:

```
company.Process = []ProcessItem{
    ProcessItem{
        ProcessItemMinimal: ProcessItemMinimal{
            Process_name: "Enquiry",
            Processtype:  0,
        },
        Sortorder: 0,
    },
    ProcessItem{
        ProcessItemMinimal: ProcessItemMinimal{
            Process_name: "Converted",
            Processtype:  1,
        },
        Sortorder: 1,
    },
}
```

You must specify `ProcessItemMinimal` when creating a struct literal because, as [the Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) says:

> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct except that they
>   cannot be used as field names in composite literals of the struct.

Comment: "You must specify ProcessItemMinimal when creating a struct literal" how to do that? Getting an error "unknown ProcessItem field 'ProcessItemMinimal' in struct literal"